# Mostrar mensaje success de formulario contacto con Sweetalert

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

Tengo un formulario simple de contacto

Necesito implementarlo con sweetalert para que sólo el mensaje de success y error se muestren con sweetalert haciendo el reset del formulario en el botón cerrar del mismo sweetalert.

Funciona bien pero por el momento sólo muestra los mensajes en el div #info y no logro implementarlo con sweetalert.

```
    <script >
    function kapat() {
        $('#info').fadeOut(500);

    }
    function gonder() {

        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.domain.com/send.php",
            data:$('#contactForm').serialize(),
            success: function(cevap) {
                $('#info').show();
                if(cevap==''){
                    $('#info').html('<div class="alert alert-success margin-bottom-30">message has been sent...</div><button type="reset" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" onClick="kapat()" >&times;</button><br />');

                }else{
                    $('#info').html('<span class="alert alert-danger">There is an Error</span><br /><input value="Close" type="reset" onClick="kapat()" />');
                }
            }

        });

    }

    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Solucionado agregando

```
Swal.fire({
icon: 'success',
title: 'Your work has been saved',
showConfirmButton: true,
}).then((result) => {
location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de tu código de

```
 $('#info').html('<div class="alert alert-success margin-bottom-30">message has been sent...</div><button type="reset" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" onClick="kapat()" >&times;</button><br />');
```

Pon el siguiente código, (omite la inclusión de la librería si, tú ya la tienes agregada)

```js
Swal.fire({
  position: 'top-end',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Your work has been saved',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

El diseño del alert varia segun lo configures, aca te dejo un ejmplo de todos los posibles

https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples

---

Si quieres que cuando le des click , limpie el formulario solo tienes que:

```
 Swal.fire({
  position: 'top-end',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Your work has been saved',
  showConfirmButton: true,
}).then(function () { $('#idFormulario').trigger("reset"); })
```

Comment: Funciona bien al mostrar el mensaje, he cambiado para que muestre un botón de ok, cómo haría para que ese botón haga el reset del formulario?

Comment: a lo que ya tienes concatenale .then(function () { $('#idFormulario').trigger("reset"); })